# Do devas have physical bodies?

Tags: gods, vedic-gods, body, mind

Do devas have bodies? Or are they purely spiritual beings?

If they do have bodies, what type of matter is it made out of?

If they don’t have bodies, then do they have physical location? Do they have length, width, and height?

Comment: Afaik, subtle body(Sukshma shareera) alone is insufficient for any experience. The subtle body of a jiva acquires a Deva shareera inorder to become a Deva , but this shareera is imperceivable by human beings

Comment: @Athrey Do Devas have length, width, and height?

Comment: duplicate question

Comment: the physical body, the outer kosha, is not the subtle body. duplicate